# Is this sentence correct grammatically? "My goal is speaking English well"

Tags: grammaticality

"My goal is speaking English well" was in my daughter's grammar test today.
She chose this was wrong as it should be, "My goal is to speak English well." However, the English teacher insists that this sentence is based on an " S+V+C "structure, so it would be correct?

Can any native English teacher clarify this issue, please?

Comment: It is grammatical, but it is describing something that my goal is doing, not describing what my goal is.

Comment: I can see plenty of examples of "my goal is" with both the to-infinitive and the ing-form in English texts. It probably relates to the general difference between the two ("to speak" and "speaking") where "to speak" is more natural in this context, for a target, while speaking is more natural for a continuous process.

Comment: This question should be on ELL.

Comment: @All This question will never get an answer if you insist in answering in comments. That means it will keep being bumped to get an answer. Please write an answer. Even a one-sentence answer is an answer (although additional corroboration is always welcome).

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented about this! This is the first time I asked on this site, so dunno how to reply!

Comment: @Stuart I'd say your point is so useful it warrants an answer; the two posted so far haven't included references (which might be difficult to source) if that's hindering you, and they don't (fully) address this point.  'My achievement / delight / forte is speaking English well' are more natural, while 'My aim / desire / intention (goals, as you say) are more natural with the to-infinitive clause.  I think 'priority' offers a choice, depending on whether it's present practice or important goal.

Comment: I suspect it's because nouns like 'goal', 'ambition', 'aim' etc. resist -ing clause predicative complementation. Reversible specifying constructions with other nouns as subject seem OK, e.g. "The most amusing thing was fooling around in the pool".

Comment: @BillJ Indeed, it seems a bit peculiar to the subject. As another example, "My chores are sweeping and vacuuming" sounds better to me than "My chores are to sweep and vacuum."

Comment: I find it interesting that a simple "inversion" to ***Speaking English well** is my goal* leads to dramatically increased "acceptability". When I run of an NGram chart comparing ***Winning the race is*** and ***To win the race is*** (case-sensitive, so most instances will match the context here), it turns out that [the infinitive is a complete no-show.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Winning+the+race+is%2CTo+win+the+race+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) So I say it's a matter of idiomatically established stylistic choice, not a "rule of grammar"

Comment: @FumbleFingers And we all know why that is. It's because "is speaking" is not a present progressive. :) It's a pesky gerund-noun. The parse would be: My goal is//speaking English well. I see  nothing weird about it. My goal is playing tennis well.

Comment: @Lambie: I can't deny I'd normally have a *preference* for the infinitive (in the non-inverted version; I'm there with the majority in favouring the gerund when it's "fronted" by reversing the copula construction). But this is definitely not a matter of "correct / incorrect".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what reference would you recommend I'd add to the answer? That the Present Progressive tense is used with the auxiliary verb "be" and the present particle of the verb + ing? What is the supporting evidence for Stuart F's assertion: "to speak" is more natural for a target but more natural for an action in progress i.e. present continuous. My answer possibly explains why the teacher believed "My goal is speaking English well” is grammatical and the **only** "correct" answer.

Comment: @M-LA I was saying to Stuart that an unsupported answer might be the best easily available in this case. I'd have addressed answerers if I thought they were being remiss. I believe ELU should primarily address the English involved, as completely and accurately as possible; after that, explanations of why some commenters might come up with some ideas might be appropriate. / As I say, I believe 'My priority is speaking English well' defaults to an 'I therefore take care in my conversations' reading while 'My priority is to speak English well' defaults to a 'So I have an elocution tutor' reading.

Answer (score 4):

One answer is that if a teacher (or textbook) is trying to test the  grasp of 'correct' (scare quotes intended) grammar, the sentence in question is not well-chosen.  As written, the sentence is ambiguous. The ambiguity arises from the fact at the word 'is' could be understood as

1. the auxiliary use of the verb to be, so that "is speaking" is the continuous present tense of the verb *to speak*, or
2. The use of that verb as the present tense of the copula, in which case, *speaking* is the verbal noun (generally called the *gerund*) of the verb *to speak*) so that "speaking English well" is a noun phrase complement.

The reason why interpretation 2 is to be preferred to 1 is not grammatical.  It is because option 1 sounds silly, and cannot possibly be what anyone could mean to say, except as a joke.

It is a mistake to use this ambiguous sentence a right/wrong choice about parsing the sentence correctly. The lesson should be about developing an awareness of the possibility of ambiguity in what we write.

So the student has, in fact, made a 'good mistake', by rephrasing the sentence to make unambiguously grammatical good as well as sensible sense, and deserves a pat on the back.

Comment: The student (and the parent) interpreted the sentence as **un**grammatical; it is the teacher that treats it as grammatical (whether as unambiguosly grammatical, or grammatical under at least one interpretation, we don't know).

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, that is so.  My point is that either the sentence is deliberately set as a 'trick' question, in the sense the sentence, as it stands, looks to a perceptive student is if there is something wrong with it (because it is grammatically ambiguous) or the grammatical ambiguity was overlooked in the setting of the question.  Either way, the pupil concerned has given a good and understandable response, and have explained that the sentence had been deliberately set to look as if there could be something wrong with it, but was not strictly un-grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] **My goal is* [*speaking English well*].
>
> [2] *My goal is* [*to speak English well*].

I'd say that the English teacher is wrong.

I suspect that [1] is unacceptable because nouns like 'goal', 'ambition', 'aim' etc. resist -*ing* clause predicative complementation of "be".

Other nouns seem OK in reversible specifying constructions, e.g. "The most amusing thing was fooling around in the pool" ~ "Fooling around in the pool was the most amusing thing".

Comment: To. Bill can I text you to ask more about this online? cuz need to clarify this clearly before  meeting English teacher.

Comment: Off-site contact is of course up to the individual, but it's discouraged. Please ask for clarification here so that the answer is useful for future enquirers too.

Comment: To me, [1] sounds perfectly fine, neither better nor worse than [2]. But I may be in the minority.

Comment: Yes, resistance. cf. *My ambition is slipping away.*

Comment: Speaking English well is definitely his goal. That is clause complementation?

Answer (score 1):

The teacher is probably thinking that the subject "My goal" anticipates a continuous tense e.g.

**He is** running the marathon ✅
**My father's best friend is** swimming across the channel tomorrow ✅
**It is** getting cold now. ✅
**My goal is** speaking English well ❌

The meaning of "goal" is similar to "ambition" and "want" which also license the infinitive.

My ambition **is** to speak English fluently. ✅
All I want **is** to speak English well. ✅
My goal **is** to speak English well. ✅

Comment: Could you clarify whether your answer is that the *-ing* version is wrong (as implied by the red symbol next to it), or that both versions are acceptable (as implied by *also*)?

Comment: @jsw29  It's "ambition" and "want" which also use the infinitive, as shown in the examples below.

Comment: I get that, but do you want to say that the analogy with *ambition* renders *speaking* incorrect or merely makes *to speak* 'more natural, as StuartF put it?

Comment: @jsw29 the red cross symbolises that the sentence is NOT in the progressive tense.

Comment: You might want to explain that it is not the progressive tense because now it looks like it is not right, which, of course, it is.

Answer (score 0):

*My goal is speaking English well* is not grammatically incorrect but it is not likely to be heard in idiomatic, native English.

The infinitive tends to complement “potential” nouns such as *goal* or *dream* or *desire*.

The gerund tends to complement “fulfilled” nouns such as *hobby* or *specialty* or *passion*.

So:

> *My goal is to speak English well.*
> *My hobby is speaking English well.*
>
> *My dream is to finish a marathon in under three hours.*
> *My specialty is finishing a marathon in under three hours.*
>
> *My desire is to bake cookies.*
> *My passion is baking cookies.*

This isn’t taught to native speakers; it just happens. And there are always exceptions.

Comment: Not idiomatic? My goal is winning the match. Of course, it'd be heard.

Comment: @Lambie — [Not much](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goal+is+winning%2Cgoal+is+to+win&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) / [`goal is to win`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=117854715) / [`goal is winning`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=117854713)

Comment: I fear you aren't using that look-up site correctly or it cannot take the full phrase: **His** goal is to win the match. And: His goal is winning the match. are perfectly grammatical. The main point here is the structure: [noun] is [to infinitive] versus noun is [gerund-noun or predicate]. And there are 13 hits on that for: my goal is to win. All in **sports** of course. https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/

Comment: @Lambie — Grammatical, yes, as I said in my opening sentence. But unusual. Just Google your sentence if you can’t follow the Ngram or Corpus results.

Comment: The structure is not unusual at all. Of course I used the COCA. See above. My plan is to win.

Comment: @Lambie — And you get 0 on [`my goal is winning`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=117855628)

Comment: You can keep repeating that forever. The structure is inherently English. So, it does not matter what you find on ngrams. Try app.Ludwig.guru "The goal is winning in November". New York Times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150367/discussion-between-tinfoil-hat-and-lambie).

Answer (score 0):

It is noteworthy, and may, at first, appear curious, that among the answers and comments on this page so far, there are some that treat ‘My goal is speaking English well’ as unidiomatic and generally odd, and some that treat it as OK. Knowledgeable, well respected, contributors to this site can be found on both sides of that split. The key to understanding this split lies in the fact that the meaning of *goal* connects the present with the future. Having a goal involves

**(1)** having something in one's mind **now**, that guides one's **current** behaviour,

**(2)** so as to produce a certain state of affairs in the **future**.

All uses of *goal* involve both, but in some of them, the focus is on (1). For example, I can say that I am goal-driven or that I am fully committed to a particular goal. These formulations are primarily about the present state of my mind. Being fully committed to a goal, for example, is a characteristic of my current state of mind, not of any result that is to be produced in the future. In some other uses of *goal*, however, the focus is on (2). We can thus speak of being goal-oriented, or of some goals being unachievable. If a goal is unachievable, it is something in the future that cannot be achieved, which is compatible with its being actually present as a goal in somebody's mind now.

In other words, having a *goal* always involves aiming at something in the future, but the word sometimes stands for the the act of aiming (and is only indirectly about what is aimed at) and sometimes for what is aimed at (and is only indirectly about the act of aiming).

When one uses *goal* in a way that focuses on (1), it calls for an infinitive with *to*; when one uses it in a way that focuses on (2), it calls for some sort of a noun-phrase, including possibly a gerund. I thus suspect that those who perceive ‘My goal is speaking English well’ as unidiomatic always use it in the former way, while those who perceive it as unproblematic are open to using it in the ways that focus on (2).

Comment: Two sides of the divide? How about both are correct?

Comment: @Lambie, everybody agrees that *to speak* is OK; what the two sides disagree about is whether *speaking* is **also** OK (where being OK includes being idiomatic, not just grammatically correct). One side says that the answer is yes, the other says that the answer is no; as a matter of logic both can't be right. You and I are both on the former side; the point of my answer was to explain why each side may seem plausible to those who defend it.